# Where to throw exception handles?

Tags: java, exception, compiler-errors

I'm trying to write a class that does data validation as the user enters data for the instance variables. There is no main method in this class only constructors. User input is done in a test harness. My question is do I do the exception handling in the set methods as I have done here? or should I do a try and catch in one of the constructors?

```
public class Customer
{
  private String fName;
  private String lName;
  private String custTIN;
  private int custNbr;
  private int custHonor;

  public Customer(String first, String last, String tin, int cust, int honor)
  {
    setFName(first);
    setLName(last);
    setCustTIN(tin);
    setCustNbr(cust);
    setCustHonor(honor);
  }

  public Customer(String first, String last, int cust, String tin)
  {
    setFName(first);
    setLName(last);
    setCustTIN(tin);
    setCustNbr(cust);
  }
  /**************************************************************************************************************
    * Set & Get Methods
   **************************************************************************************************************/

  public void setFName(String first) throws InvalidCustomerException
  {
    if(first == "null")
    {
     throw new InvalidCustomerException("You did not enter any data");
    }
       else
       {
        fName = first;
       }
  }

  public void setLName(String last)
  {
   lName = last;
  }

  public void setCustTIN(String tin)
  {
   custTIN = tin;
  }

  public void setCustNbr(int cust)
  {
   custNbr = cust;
  }

  public void setCustHonor(int honor)
  {
   custHonor = honor;
  }

  public String getFName()
  {
   return fName;
  }

  public String getLName()
  {
   return lName;
  }

  public String getCustTIN()
  {
   return custTIN;
  }

  public int getCustNbr()
  {
   return custNbr;
  }

  public int getCustHonor()
  {
   return custHonor;
  }

  /****************************************************************************************************************
    * toString Methods
   ****************************************************************************************************************/
  //public String createSalutaion()
  {
  }//end createSalutation()


  public String toString()
  {
    return String.format ("%d %s %s, Customer number %d, with Tax Id: %s", getCustHonor(), getFName(), getLName(), getCustNbr(), getCustTIN());
  }//end toString()

}
```

Here is my exception class.....

```
/**
 * Auto Generated Java Class.
 */
public class InvalidCustomerException extends Exception
{
  private String inputValue = "null";

  public InvalidCustomerException(String message) 
  { 
   super(message);
  }

  public InvalidCustomerException(String message, Throwable cause)
  {
   super(message,
        cause);
  }

  public InvalidCustomerException(String message, String inputValue)
  {

  }

  public InvalidCustomerException(String message, String inputValue, Throwable cause)
  {

  }


} // end of invalid customer exception
```

Comment: It depends on the contract you establish with you object.  In most case, I might do some validation in both places, so if the object is expecting a number, I'd make sure that what the user inputs is a number, but the object might then perform it's own validation to make sure it's a prime number with a given range

Comment: As a note, did you mean `== null`? If not, (1) that's a really weird constraint and (2) you need to use `equals`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like to make sure that bad data never gets passed in the first place, with try-catches and throwing of errors (IllegalArgumentException, generally, because it is, after all) in whatever is collecting the data passed to the constructor.

But to answer your question, it would probably be best to intercept the errors as soon as possible to avoid undefined behavior or garbage in garbage out in later functions that rely on input data being correct, with, and this is the thing here, the ability to resubmit input that got messed up.  But as you don't directly set your instance variables, your setup works well enough, as long as you can get data from the user to rectify whatever got messed up.